# spring aspects working without explicit definition in application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, applicationcontext

In my project, I have an aspect defined as follows:

```
@Aspect
public class UselessAspect {

@Around("execution(* com.x.y.UselessClass.*.*(..))")
public Object logAroundUselessClassMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // following method does exist and its doing whats desired
        return logBeforeAndAfterTheMethod(joinPoint);
    }
}
```

I do not have anything like following in my application context:

```
<bean id="uselessAspect" class="com.z.UselessAspect" />
```

My question is - why is my aspect working as expected? My perception was that the aspect is required to be in spring application context. What is the difference between having that aspect in application context and not having that aspect in application context?

**EDIT**

In my applicationcontext.xml, I only have

```
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com"></context:component-scan>
```

Comment: do you enable aspectj proxy in your app context?

Comment: @Aspect annotation should be interpreted somehow, so one of the spring post processor should be in charge. That's why your aspectj have worked. Also spring requires that everything should be managed in application context if you wanted to use it in spring context. Also there can be workarounds like a custom post processors who can "autowire" or "wire" some beans in not spring managed class

Comment: I only have <context:spring-configured/>. aspectj autoproxy is not enabled.

Comment: Where is it working? In your IDE (eclipse with aspectj tooling installed) or at runtime when deployed outside of the IDE.

Comment: when deployed outside ide and when deployed from inside ide as well

Comment: Do you maybe compile and the aspect with the AspectJ compiler *Ajc*? In this case it would be applied during compile time and be independent of Spring altogether. If you intend to use Spring AOP, do not use *Ajc*.

Comment: Oh. I think thats whats going on. I am using maven aspectj compiler plugin.